# Awaitable task in not awaited task

Tags: c#, async-await, task, dotnet-httpclient

I'm working on a little console application that selects messages from a database queue 
and forwards the messages to a rest api (ASP.NET Web Api).

In general the application does the following steps:

1. Get the number of pending messages
2. Load the last pending messages
3. Post the message to the rest api
4. Remove the message from the database

To make the program more flexible and to have the ability to process every single message
in a separate database transcation the steps 2 - 3 will be executed as tasks.

This means if there are four messages in the database, we'll have four tasks that
should run nearly parallel and process the messages.

This is what the code looks like:

Database message

```
public class DatabaseMessage 
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

UnitOfWork (Interface IUnitOfWork)

```
public class UnitOfWork 
{
    // ... extermely simplified
    public int GetNumberOfPendingMessages() { ... }
    public DatabaseMessage GetNextPendingMessage() { ... }
    public void DeleteMessage(DatabaseMessage message) { ... }
}
```

HttpService (Interface IHttpService)

```
public class HttpService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public HttpService() 
    {
        _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        /* Some initalization stuff for the HttpClient object */
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponse> PostMessage(DatabaseMessage message) 
    {
        var content = /* Create content object */
        return await _httpClient.PostAsync(..., content);
    }
}
```

MessageProcessingService (Interface IMessageProcessingService)

```
public class MessageProcessingService 
{
    private readonly IHttpService _httpService;
    private readonly Semaphore _databaseProcessingSemaphore;

    public MessageProcessingService(IHttpService httpService) 
    {
        _httpService = httpService;
    }

    public async Task ProcessDatabaseMessages() 
    {
        var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
        var numberOfPendingMessages = unitOfWork.GetNumberOfPendingMessages();

        var messageProcessingTasks = new List<Task>();

        for(int t = 0; t < numberOfPendingMessages; t++) 
        {
            messageProcessingTasks.Add(new Task(() => {
                ProcessMessageAsTask();
            }));
        }

        var continuationHandler = Task.WhenAll(messageProcessingTasks);

        messageProcessingTasks.ForEach(e => e.Start());

        await continuationHandler;
    }

    private void ProcessMessageAsTask() 
    {
        // Single unit of work for each tasks
        var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();

        try{
            // Starting a database transaction
            unitOfWork.StartTransaction();
            _databaseProcessingSemaphore.OnWait();
            var message = unitOfWork.GetNextPendingMessage();
            _databaseProcessingSemaphore.Release();

            if(message != null) 
            {
                var response = _httpService.PostMessage(message).Result;

                if(response == HttpStatus.OK) 
                {
                    unitOfWork.DeleteMessage(message);
                    unitOfWork.Commit();
                }
                else 
                {
                    unitOfWork.Rollback();
                }

            }
            else 
            {
                unitOfWork.Commit();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
            unitOfWork.Rollback();
            // Further error handling...
        }
    }
}
```

For better understanding, the HttpClient object is created and managed by [Unity](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity) and is injected
into the MessageProcessingService object. The HttpClient is held as singleton in the container.

I'm facing now the problem that the call of the method `_httpService.PostMessage()`. For example, if there are five
messages in the message queue, the call fails five times with an exception that tells me that an task has been canceled.

My question is now what is the problem with PostAsync call of the .NET HttpClient? Is the issue caused by the `.Result` option or would
it be better to create a new instance of the HttpClient for each message processing task?
Or is there a general problem with the architecture with tasks and the processing of rest api calls?

**Update 2018-04-04 - 08:09**

I've now made the method `ProcessMessageAsTask` async and I'm awaiting now the call of the `HttpService`.
But now I don't get any exception at all. In the ressource monitor and while debugging I can see that all tasks reach the call of the `HttpClient` (`return await _httpClient.PostAsync(..., content);`)
But there is no exception nor will the messages be posted. But I don't get any exceptions. The program will be closed immediately after the calls of the `HttpClient`. All futher statements were not processed.

Changes:

```
public async Task ProcessDatabaseMessages() 
{
    var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
    var numberOfPendingMessages = unitOfWork.GetNumberOfPendingMessages();

    var messageProcessingTasks = new List<Task>();

    for(int t = 0; t < numberOfPendingMessages; t++) 
    {
        messageProcessingTasks.Add(new Task(async () => {
            await ProcessMessageAsTask();
        }));
    }

    var continuationHandler = Task.WhenAll(messageProcessingTasks);

    messageProcessingTasks.ForEach(e => e.Start());

    await continuationHandler;
}

private async Task ProcessMessageAsTask() 
{
    // Single unit of work for each tasks
    var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();

    try{
        // Starting a database transaction
        unitOfWork.StartTransaction();
        _databaseProcessingSemaphore.OnWait();
        var message = unitOfWork.GetNextPendingMessage();
        _databaseProcessingSemaphore.Release();

        if(message != null) 
        {
            var response = await _httpService.PostMessage(message);

            if(response == HttpStatus.OK) 
            {
                unitOfWork.DeleteMessage(message);
                unitOfWork.Commit();
            }
            else 
            {
                unitOfWork.Rollback();
            }

        }
        else 
        {
            unitOfWork.Commit();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) 
    {
        unitOfWork.Rollback();
        // Further error handling...
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to create separate instances for other reasons but using the result property is a bad thing to do especially in this kind of app. Make `ProcessMessageAsTask` is async

Comment: show the exception detail with callstack plz. And yes .Result is evil most of the time

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `.Result` (which blocks your method) and did not make `ProcessMessageAsTask()` truly `async`? `.Result` is generally bad and you should follow async-all-the-way, since blocking methods can add hidden complexities like context-deadlocking.

Comment: @ethane Thinking about it in detail there is no real reason. But I think this is not the real point where the program breaks. As described I think the problem is that the HttpClient is not thread safety.

Comment: @Fabian, respectfully, there are few worrying lines in the code snippet with regards to `async` programming in .NET. Have you tried changing `ProcessMessageAsTask()` to `async Task ProcessMessageAsTask()` and `await`ing `PostMessage()` instead?

Comment: @ethane Thanks for your suggestion. I think I got that point and I‘ll fix it right now. But nevertheless I think this is not causing the described exception.

Comment: You need to post full stack trace of mentioned exception not just vague description.

Comment: @Evk: I've updated my initial post with the new infos.

Comment: The current problem after your async revision is the usage of `new Task(Action)` in `ProcessDatabaseMessages()`

`new Task()` doesn't have an overload that takes a Func<T> to await on the Task when executed. You'll want to use `Task.Run()` which has an appropriate override to handle async. It also saves you from having to explicitly start the task as it creates and starts all in one call.

 `messageProcessingTasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => {
            await ProcessMessageAsTask();
        }));`

This may just get you back to your original problem but will at least eliminate that. :)